Event study of a merge
I want to see whether the announcement of the merge between CaixaBank and Bankia had a stats significantly impacted Caixabank's stock returns, but I am not sure the method I'm using is correct. I have data about daily Caixabank's stock prices and daily IBEX 35. I computed the subnormal returns by subtracting the IBEX return (used as the expected normal returns) from the realized return each day. Initially I have three periods: event day, anticipation period (10 days before ED), and adjustment period (10 days after ED). I computed the cumulative a normal returns of each period. Does it make sense to compute the t-statistic of the CAR for each period (under the null hypothesis that the CAR is zero) for the purpose of my analysis. If not, do you have any sugestion on how to test this?

Greetings and thanks do not belong in the posts on Stack Exchange sites, so I have removed them. Thank you for being polite, though!
